# creating a maze with depth first search

Tags: java, algorithm, graph

I'm trying to create a maze with depth first search algorithm and I've tried with both stack and recursive algorithms and I tested the algorithms on prior examples and they worked fine but I can't get it to work with the maze. I also think the way I'm displaying the maze is wrong.

```
public void depthFirstSearch(){  
    for(int row = 0; row < dim; row++){
        for(int column = 0; column < dim; column++){

            Node current    =   maze[row][column];
            if(!current.isVisited()){
                search(current);
            }
        }
    }
}

    public void search(Node node){

        node.visit();
        Random rand  =   new Random();
        int direction   =   rand.nextInt(4);

//west wall
        if(direction == 0 && left(node) != null && !left(node).isVisited()){
            node.breakLeft();
            left(node).breakRight();
            search(left(node));
        }

//east wall
        if(direction == RIGHT_DIRECTION && right(node) != null && !right(node).isVisited()){
            node.breakRight();
            right(node).breakLeft();
            search(right(node));
        }

//south wall
        if(direction == BOTTOM_DIRECTION && down(node) != null && !down(node).isVisited())
        {
            node.breakDown();
            down(node).breakUp();
            search(down(node));
        }

//north wall
        if(direction == TOP_DIRECTION && up(node) != null && !up(node).isVisited()){
            node.breakUp();
            up(node).breakDown();
            search(up(node));
        }
    }

public char[][] fillMaze(){
    depthFirstSearch();
    char[][] filledMaze  =   new char[dim][dim];

    for(int row = 0; row < dim; row++)
        for(int column = 0; column < dim; column++){
             //Fill left wall
            if(inRange(row, column - 1) && maze[row][column].left && filledMaze[row][column - 1] != '#')
                filledMaze[row][column - 1] = '#';

            //Fill top wall
            if(inRange(row - 1, column) && maze[row][column].up && filledMaze[row - 1][column] != '#')
                filledMaze[row - 1][column] = '#';

            //Fill right wall
            if(inRange(row, column + 1) && maze[row][column].right && filledMaze[row][column + 1] != '#')
                filledMaze[row][column + 1] = '#';

            //Fill bottom wall
            if(inRange(row + 1, column) && maze[row][column].down && filledMaze[row + 1][column] != '#')
                filledMaze[row + 1][column] = '#';    
        }

    return filledMaze;
}

    public void drawMaze(char[][] filledMaze){
    for(int row = 0; row < dim; row++){
        for(int column = 0; column < dim; column++){
            if(filledMaze[row][column] != '#') {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            else {
               System.out.print("#"); 
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

output for a 10x10 maze where | represents a wall, here the maze basically all walls:

```
||||||||||
||||||||||
||||||||||
||||||||||
||||||||||
||||||||||
||||||||||
||||||||||
||||||||||
||||||||||
```

So the maze is very dense and if I switch to stack algorithm of dfs it's a little better but I feel there is something very wrong with either the way I'm drawing the maze or the way I have implemented dfs to create the maze..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in printing definitely. I tried your implementation for DFS and it works, and because I don't understand implementation for printing I created my own.

The idea for printing is that Every `Node` has its own `nodeMat[3][3]` and it will be filled with `#` i.e.:

```
###
#
#
```

And later just print whole maze with:

```
for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
    for (int nodeRow = 0; nodeRow < 3; nodeRow++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < matrix.length; col++) {
            Node cur = matrix[row][col];
            cur.printRow(nodeRow);
            if (col == matrix.length - 1)
                System.out.println();
       }
    }
}
```

The maze looks like:

```
##############################
# ## ## ##    ##    ## ## ## #
# ##########  ####  ##########
# ########### #####  #########
# ## ## ## ## ## ##       ## #
#### ## ################  ####
###  ## #################  ###
#    ## ## ## ##       ##    #
########## #####  ###  #######
#########  ####  #####  ######
# ## ##    ##    ## ##    ## #
#######  ####  #### ##########
#######  ###  ####  ##########
#    ##       ##    ## ## ## #
###################### ## ####
###################### ##  ###
# ## ## ## ##       ## ##    #
# ##### ## ########### ####  #
# ##### ##  ########## ##### #
# ## ## ##    ## ## ## ## ## #
######################### ## #
######################### ## #
#       ##    ## ## ## ## ## #
######  ####  ########### ####
####### #####  ########## ####
# ## ## ## ##    ## ## ## ## #
##############################
##############################
# ## ## ##       ##    ## ## #
##############################
```

You see that there is no single path from one corner to another. This is because when you call `search(node)` you give only one chance to find non visited `Node`.

I add one `list` with numbers `0,1,2,3`. Each number is position LEFT,RIGHT,UP,DOWN. And added two methods to the class `Node`

```
public boolean randomExist() {
    return list.size()>0;
}

public int getRandom() {
    int randomNumber = random.nextInt(list.size());
    return list.remove(randomNumber);
}
```

And change `search(node)` method to:

```
public void search(Node node) {
node.visit();

while (node.randomExist()) {
    int direction = node.getRandom();
    if (direction == LEFT && leftOK(node) && !left(node).isVisited()) {
        node.breakLeft();
        left(node).breakRight();
        search(left(node));
        return;
    }

    if (direction == RIGHT && rightOK(node) && !right(node).isVisited()){
        node.breakRight();
...
```

Important part is `return` statement in `if` statement.

Now maze looks much better:

```
##############################
#       ##       ##    ##    #
######  ##  ###  ##    #######
#######    #####    ##  ######
#    ##    ## ##    ##       #
#    ######## #############  #
# ## #######  #############  #
# ## ##       ## ## ##       #
# ## ##  ####### ## ##  ######
# ##    #######  ## ## #######
# ##    ## ##    ## ## ##    #
# ######## ##  #### ## ####  #
# ######## ##  ###  ##  #### #
# ##    ## ##       ##    ## #
# ######## #############  ## #
#  ####### ############## ## #
#       ## ##          ## ## #
######  #####  ######  ## ## #
#######  #### ########    ## #
#    ##    ## ##    ##    ## #
###  ####  ## ##    ######## #
#### #####    ## ##  ####### #
# ## ## ##    ## ##       ## #
#### ## ######## ########### #
###  ## #######  ##########  #
#    ## ##       ## ##       #
#  #######  ####### ##  ######
#  ######  #######  ##  ######
#          ##       ##       #
##############################
```

Comment: My randomizing and dfs are similar although you have only chosen to break left and right walls rather than all 4 directions, is there any reason for this? Also I'm not quite sure I follow what you were trying to do with the formatting of nodeMat[3][3] - I was basically using all 4 directions and if there was a wall in that direction I would draw it (not including duplicates)

Comment: No-no, I also break all four walls but the rest of code is same as for LEFT and RIGHT, same implementation as yours. So I didn't write it.

I look every node as position where 'user' can stand. 'User' can go up,down.right or left depends on walls. So every Node has four booleans, every for each wall (I assumed that this is your impl also). End later in printing I need to draw these walls. It can't be done whit 2x2 matrix because (in that case) there is no place for 'user' standing. So it is 3x3, Center should always be empty and ### is drawn on edges.

You are right, edges duplicates now.

Comment: Oh sorry missread. What was your printRow()? I was basically putting a wall '#' at left,right, up, down indexes from the current node in the char[][] array before printing when printing as you saw

Comment: With how many '#' you represent one node?  I represent each node with 3x3 matrix so i can't print whole block (with 2 or 3 prinln() calls) and then go at the top of the row for next block(from right side). So if we look just first row (10 nodes) there are 3x30 signs('#' or 'blank'). So I need to scan through all nodes but only print the first layer, then prinln(),then scan through same 10 nodes but now printing second layer, then println(),and finally printing third (bottom) layer of nodes. Then is called prinln() and I go to the second row of the maze. And procedure is repeating.